# Table of Content (TOC) with numbers

Tags: gui-design, lists, numbers

The Table of Content at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random) use numbers for an ordered list.
[image]

But the headline doens't start with this number.
Why?
It look wrongs for me, maybe because I'm used to the same result as in books with chapters.
I think a number in the headline (1. History) looks like a ordered list with steps that must be followed in order like a cook recipe. But without a dot like "1 History" doesn't look right.
Is there a UX best practice to use numbering in a headline like a chapter with an index (TOC)?

Comment: I think it makes sense for the contents to be numbered, as there usually is a logical ordering to the article sections--for example, a biographical article typically has a loose chronological ordering. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry, my question is. Why don't use Wikipedia numer in the front of the Headline? Is it while it looks like a ordered list that must use (read) in this order? If yes: the final Q is what is the best practise to use number in the headline that don't look: "you must read it in this order".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Wikipedia's numbering is *mostly* redundant.

---

### Why did Wikipedia number the contents at all?

#### From a UX perspective, **people expect the table of contents to be numbered**

- Because books have numbered contents.
- Without the numbers, it wouldn't be so immediately obvious that it's a table of contents.

#### It's *unlikely* the numbers are there for citation purposes

- I've not found a single instance where somebody has cited the section number of a Wiki.
- No major referencing guides (Harvard/APA/Chicago/IEEE) accommodate section numbers in references to Wikipedia articles.

---

### Why did Wikipedia not put the section number before the headings?

One justification might be that it's not required on websites because you can use hyperlinks instead.

But the **heading numbers are missing from the *Printable Version* and *Create a Book* version** too.

This backs up that there's no other purpose aside from **making the contents look like contents**.

---

### What's the best practice for numbering?

There *are* benefits to numbering your headings.

As [Devin](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/54669/devin) writes in the comments:

> [There is] the need of numbers to follow a mental path, specially in long articles. For example, if in TOC I click on item list 4, having a numbered header will remind me of the items I left behind just in case I need to go back to find some information.

Comment: good answer. However, made me think about the need of numbers to follow a mental path, specially in long articles. For example, if in TOC  I click on item list 4, having a numbered header will remind me of the items I left behind just in case I need to go back to find some information

Comment: @Devin I should clarify, my answer is explaining "Why doesn't the headline start with this number?" rather than answering "Is there a UX best practice to use numbering in a headline?". From a UX/IA perspective, I absolutely agree that the numbers should be before the section headings. I'll adjust my answer so that it addresses both.

Comment: it was just a comment , I didn't mean it was incorrect, just got me thinking, as a matter of fact I voted up you r answer :)

Comment: It's okay, I didn't think that was the case :) I've quoted you in my answer if that's okay? I figured that you had already explained the point so well that it wasn't worth me re-hashing it.

Comment: 100% agree with you. What do think is the difference between a 1. Head, 1 Head and 1 - Head? The first one look to me like a step by step number like a story book.